# Navbar horizontal drowpdown items height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a navbar with a dropdown menu. The dropdown items are displayed horizontally in full width and with a larger height. When the items dont fit (mobile view) I want them to be displayed one bellow the other in full width and in smaller (normal) height

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4965884a/2/

Comment: `.navbar-default .dropdown-menu > li {
    display: block;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: left;
}` using this will solve the issue for mobile devices, if that's what you're seeking.

Comment: Thank you. I tried but now they are not side by side in desktop view

Comment: that's why I wrote **for mobile devices**, means use `media-query`.

Comment: can you update my fiddle?

Comment: here is the updated [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/4965884a/4) and for the max-width you can change it as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add following css in you css file

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
{
     .navbar-default .dropdown-menu > li {
          display:block;
     }
}
```